# strip some value from a column -pandas/python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In my pandas data frame I have a column DM with some data, I want to strip only 2 letters from that one.

```
DM
OLDE-T
OLAT-T
OLFR-T
OLPL-T
OLNL-T
OLBE-T
OLES-T
OLCH-T
OLIT-T
OLROET
OLDE-T
```

my desired solution is

```
DE
AT
FR
PL
NL
BE
ES
CH
IT
ROE
DE
```

basically, I want to remove `OL` from the beginning and `-T` from the ending.

one catch is that when the value is `OLROET` then we don't have `-T` in the end, here we have only `T`.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `^` for start of string and `$` for end of string with `[-]*` for possible value `-` before `T`:

```
df['DM'] = df['DM'].replace(['^OL', '[-]*T$'], '', regex=True)
print (df)
     DM
0    DE
1    AT
2    FR
3    PL
4    NL
5    BE
6    ES
7    CH
8    IT
9   ROE
10   DE
```

Comment: how to elegantly handle second last row? maybe ```-?T$``` as regex?

Comment: @SreeramTP - one idea in answer, maybe exist nicer.